# Ruby( on Rails) LINQ .Select data transformation equivalent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linq, equivalent

So let's say I have an array of strings in C#, I could convert this array of strings to an array of integers using the following LINQ statement:

```
(new[] {"1", "2", "3"}).Select(x => int.parse(x))
```

Is there a Ruby equivalent to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what `Select` means in C#, but converting an array of strings to array of integers is quite simple: `["1", "2", "3"].map(&method(:Integer))`

Comment: Ah, so .map is used for data transformation then. I had seen that used one at some point didn't get a real understanding of what was happening, but now it makes perfect sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but @Victor `Select` is C#'s version of `map`. It's named that way to imitate SQL and reduce the cognitive dissonance when you switch back and forth between the two.

Comment: @James, the other really important ruby sequence method is `filter` (for C#'s `Where`).  In all the ruby methods you can use any callable as the parameter like a proc or lambda, just like in C#, but the syntax is a bit wonkier (on the other hand, creating an inline array in C# is quite wonky).

Answer (score 1):

A more shorter solution:

```
["1", "2", "3"].map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: There is a difference though: `["1", "2", "a3"].map(&:to_i) #=> [1, 2, 0]`. I tried to avoid it.